# why ubuntu showing error while running lex program

Tags: ubuntu, flex-lexer, yacc, lex

I am trying to run  a lexical program in UBUNTU with `.l` file extension, I already installed flex and bison, and I was able to get lex.yy.c file, but when I give command `cc lex.yy.c -lfd` or `cc lex.yy.c` the terminal showed an error:

```
first.l:2:10: fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory
 #include <iostream>
          ^~~~~~~~~~
```

my code is:

```
%{
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define YY_DECL extern "C" int yylex()
%}
%%
[ \t\n]         ;
[0-9]+\.[0-9]+  { cout << "Found a floating-point number:" << yytext                         << endl;   }
[0-9]+          { cout << "Found an integer:" << yytext << endl; }
[a-zA-Z0-9]+    { cout << "Found a string: " << yytext << endl; }
%%
 int main(int, char**) {
    // lex through the input:
    yylex();
}
```

I reinstall flex and bison ans also uninstall and install gcc, but no change! Any help will be greatly appreciated,

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here is the correct code to run it:

```
%%
[0-9]+\.[0-9]*  { printf("Found a floating-point number:"); }
[0-9]*          { printf("Found an integer:"); }
[a-zA-Z0-9]*    { printf("Found a string: "); }
%%
main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
 yylex();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to compile C++ code with a C compiler. Use `g++` instead.

Comment: /tmp/ccTKLswl.o: In function `yylex':
lex.yy.c:(.text+0x545): undefined reference to `yywrap'
/tmp/ccTKLswl.o: In function `yyinput()':
lex.yy.c:(.text+0x1187): undefined reference to `yywrap'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: I tried with "gcc lex.yy.c -lfd" and I got the same first error:   "first.l:2:10: fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory
 #include <iostream>
          ^~~~~~~~~~
"

Comment: @HasibulKabir You'll need to either link against `libfl` (using `-lfl` - same as with gcc), define your own `yywrap` or use `%option noyywrap` or the equivalent command line option to `flex`.

Comment: I found the solution: I have modified the code, and running successfully! Code is Here:   %%
[0-9]+\.[0-9]*  { printf("Found a floating-point number:"); }
[0-9]*          { printf("Found an integer:"); }
[a-zA-Z0-9]*    { printf("Found a string: "); }
%%
main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
 yylex();
}